# Jasmine / Karma: Error: Spies must be created in a before function or a spec

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Spies must be created in a before function or a spec
```

My Test code should be sound:

```
describe 'A spy', ->
  foo = undefined
  bar = null
  beforeEach ->
    foo = setBar: (value) ->
      bar = value
      return
    spyOn foo, 'setBar'
    foo.setBar 123
    foo.setBar 456, 'another param'
    return
  it 'tracks that the spy was called', ->
    expect(foo.setBar).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 0):

Turnsout I had `mocha` and `jasmine` declared inside my `karma.conf.js`. As a result the frameworks interpreted both beforeEach differently.

Dropping `mocha` from my karma config file worked.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create your spy inside the `beforeEach` block.